# issue with login to web server

Tags: android, mysql, authentication, session-management

i have an issue with my project.
1. I have a web server in www.kinandayu.com , i success to make a sign up system in www.kinandayu.com/data_signup.php
2. I want to make a login system in my aplication. I have code like below :

```
package com.example.mdesigntemp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.util.Log;

public class SignInJSON {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

public SignInJSON() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}

public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if (method == "POST") {
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } else if (method == "GET") {
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

this is signinactivity.java

```
package com.example.mdesigntemp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

ActionBar actionbar;
TextView textview;
LayoutParams layoutparams;
Button btlogin;
EditText edEmail, edPassword;
SessionManager session;
String url, success;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    getActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);

    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "User Login Status: " + session.isLoggedIn(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();

    btlogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btlogin);
    edEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edEmail);
    edPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edPassword);
    TextView registerScreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btDaftar);

    registerScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignupActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });

    btlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        //String email = edEmail.getText().toString();
        //String password = edPassword.getText().toString();
        //String theemail = email.replace("" , "%20");
        //String thepassword = password.replace("", "%20");
        url = "http://www.kinandayu.com/data_login.php" + "email="
                + edEmail.getText().toString() + "password="
                + edPassword.getText().toString();


        if (edEmail.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0
                && edPassword.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) 
        {
            new Masuk().execute();
        } 
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field is empty!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        }
    });
}

public class Masuk extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
{
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait a moment ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        SignInJSON jParser = new SignInJSON();

        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try {
            success = json.getString("success");

            Log.e("error", "nilai sukses=" + success);

            JSONArray result = json.getJSONArray("kinanday_TesDB");

            if (success.equals("1")) {

                for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject c = result.getJSONObject(i);

                    //String password = c.getString("password").trim();
                    String email = c.getString("email").trim();
                    session.createLoginSession(email);
                    Log.e("ok", " ambil data");

                }
            } else {
                Log.e("erro", "tidak bisa ambil data 0");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {                
            Log.e("erro", "tidak bisa ambil data 1");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (success.equals("1")) {
            Intent in = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
            finish();
    }  else {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect Email Or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
}
```

this is sessionmanager.java :

```
package com.example.mdesigntemp;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.text.LoginFilter.UsernameFilterGeneric;
@SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
public class SessionManager {
// Shared Preferences
SharedPreferences pref;

// Editor for Shared preferences
Editor editor;

// Context
Context _context;

// Shared pref mode
int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

// nama sharepreference
private static final String PREF_USERNAME = "Sesi";

// All Shared Preferences Keys
private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";
public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";

// Constructor
public SessionManager(Context context){
    this._context = context;
    pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_USERNAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
}

/**
 * Create login session
 * */
public void createLoginSession(String email){
    // Storing login value as TRUE
    editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);

    editor.putString(KEY_EMAIL, email);
    editor.commit();
}   

/**
 * Check login method wil check user login status
 * If false it will redirect user to login page
 * Else won't do anything
 * */
public void checkLogin(){
    // Check login status
    if(!this.isLoggedIn()){
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, MainActivity.class);

        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        _context.startActivity(i);
        //((Activity)_context).finish();
    }

}

/**
 * Get stored session data
 * */
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();

    user.put(KEY_USERNAME, pref.getString(KEY_USERNAME, null));
    user.put(KEY_EMAIL, pref.getString(KEY_EMAIL, null));

    return user;
}

/**
 * Clear session details
 * */
public void logoutUser(){
    // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();

    Intent i = new Intent(_context, MainActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    _context.startActivity(i);
}

public boolean isLoggedIn(){
    return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
}
}
```

The problem is when i try to login with correct username and correct password, aplication will take me to activiy main(work) . but it will take me to the activity when username is correct but the password is not. And when the email is wrong aplication will force stop. i take this code from this (http://adi-hidayat.com/android-login-logout-dengan-android-mysql/) tutorial but i dont know where is the mistake. any answer is very help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
    url = "http://www.kinandayu.com/data_login.php" + "email="
            + edEmail.getText().toString() + "password="
            + edPassword.getText().toString();
```

I would like to advise you to abandon this code entirely and start over. It is extremely insecure and will have your user's passwords being transmitted in clear text over an insecure `http` connection.

I realize this is not the answer you probably wanted to hear ... you should take a look at how other services and apps implement [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) as one example of building a secure login system.

Comment: should i change my web server with https ?

Comment: That would certainly be a start :) here's another article that talks about ways to make a secure API that can be consumed from mobile apps: https://stormpath.com/blog/secure-your-rest-api-right-way